# Sorting and Searching

Tags: c, sorting, search, bubble-sort

I am working on a recitation exercise for my C programming class. I try to figure it out on my own but I have a couple of questions.  I've been given the following information:

General algorithm (not in C) for the Bubble Sort: <-- Not sure what it means by "not in C"

Problems #1 thru #2 refer to the following array:
      `30  20  10  5  40  35  25`

```
bChange = TRUE;
for i=0; i < (N-1) and bChange; i=i+1
{
  bChange = FALSE;
  for j=0; j < N-i-1; j=j+1
  {
    if key[j+1] < key[j]
    {
        Exchange R[j] and R[j+1];
        bChange = TRUE;
    }
  }
}
```

1. What is the maximum number of executions of the body of the outer for loop in the Bubble Sort for that array? My answer is ***4***
2. What is the maximum total executions of the body of the inner for loop in the Bubble Sort for that array?
   1st major iteration?
   2nd major iteration?
   3rd major iteration?
   4th major iteration?
   5th major iteration?
   6th major iteration?
   Total is ?
   Total:   ***4***  = the body of the inner for executes  ***2*** times

This code was given to me like this, there is no main function or anything else just that to be figured it out.

Comment: "not in C" just means that this isn't real C code. For example you cannot write `Exchange R[j] and R[j+1];` in a real program.

Comment: you could code that in C, then add a counter to count the inner loop iterations.

Comment: What's the answer that you _don't_ want us to give you?

Comment: the numbers in bold and italic, I mean I honestly just want to analyze your points of view and figure it out. I feel I'm to dependable by asking too many questions.

Comment: You claim that the outer loop executes 4 times, but then you have 6 major iterations in answer 2. Please explain what you mean by *"major iteration"*. Also, what does *"5 for 20"* mean?

Comment: Also if the inner loop doesn't execute for a major iteration the outer loop will stop executing

Comment: don't pay attention to "5 for 20" I wrote it myself, I forgot to take it out. 
About the major iteration that's how the document came with, the TA wasn't really explanatory about it on.

Comment: A "major iteration" is an iteration of the outer loop, I would guess.

Comment: I agree that a *"major iteration"* is an iteration of the outer loop. So the question for @ArmvadEzikon is how many times does the inner loop execute on the first iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: 6 times for iteration 1